# How do I test with Rspec an initialize method that invokes find_or_initialize_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

How do I write a test to check for the `find_or_initialize_by` block in this `initialize` method?

```
def initialize(document, user)
  @document = document
  @api = @document.api_version
  @template = @document.template
  @user = user
  @brand = @user.brand
  @vars = master_var_hash.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFind

  template_variables.each do |t|
    @document.template_variables.find_or_initialize_by(name: t.name) do |d|
      d.name           = t.name
      d.tag            = t.tag
      d.box_name       = t.box_name
      d.designator     = t.designator
      d.order_index    = t.order_index
      d.master_id      = t.id
      d.editable       = t.editable
      d.editable_title = t.editable_title
      d.html_box       = t.box.stack.html_box if @api == :v3
      d.text = t.name == 'title' ? default_title : user_value(t)
    end
  end
end
```

I want to be able to test that the right values have been assigned to the `@document`'s `TemplateVariables` from the class' `TemplateVariable`s. In my coverage report I can't even hit inside the `find_or_initialize_by` block.

My test for size doesn't really check what I want to test here:

```
describe 'template_variables' do
  it 'initializes all the new vars per document' do
    expect(document.template_variables.size).to eq subject.master_var_hash.size
  end
end
```

How can I write a test to check all those values and cover those lines?

Comment: Do you not get the coverage when creating a new instance with .new?

Comment: No, which is the curious thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

`expect(document).to receive_message_chain(:template_variables, :find_or_initialize_by).exactly(8).times`

but it's a mess and you would have to also check if each call got proper parameters.

I would suggest extracting this to a method: 
`Document#initialize_variables(template_variables)`

then you could test it as simply as

`expect(document).to receive(:initialize_variables).with(expected_hash)`

and then you can cover `Document#initialize_variables` with specs and test it's behavior in depth.